# The "size" field in directory entry meaning for directories?

Tags: filesystem, directory, fat32

I'm looking at low-level directory structure of a disk partition, formatted as "vfat" filesystem. The directory entry structure I use is:

```
struct __attribute__ ((packed)) Dentry
{
  char          name[11];
  Attr          attr;
  uint8_t       reserved;
  uint8_t       ctimeTenth;
  Time          ctime;
  Date          cdate;
  Date          adate;
  uint16_t      clusterHi;
  Time          mtime;
  Date          mdate;
  uint16_t      clusterLo;
  uint32_t      size;
};
```

So, the last four bytes of the directory entry should represent size of file or directory in bytes. However, in my experiments directory entries for **directories** (not files) always have zero in the `size` field. For example, this is `dd` dump of my root directory with one file and one **non-empty** subdirectory (named `qqq`):

```
00000000  42 65 00 65 00 66 00 66  00 66 00 0f 00 fe 00 00  |Be.e.f.f.f......|
00000010  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff 00 00 ff ff ff ff  |................|
00000020  01 61 00 61 00 61 00 62  00 62 00 0f 00 fe 62 00  |.a.a.a.b.b....b.|
00000030  63 00 63 00 63 00 64 00  64 00 00 00 64 00 65 00  |c.c.c.d.d...d.e.|
00000040  41 41 41 42 42 42 7e 31  20 20 20 20 00 64 43 60  |AAABBB~1    .dC`|
00000050  d1 44 d1 44 00 00 43 60  d1 44 04 00 0b 00 00 00  |.D.D..C`.D......|
00000060  41 71 00 71 00 71 00 00  00 ff ff 0f 00 3d ff ff  |Aq.q.q.......=..|
00000070  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff 00 00 ff ff ff ff  |................|
00000080  51 51 51 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 10 00 00 20 79  |QQQ        ... y|
00000090  d1 44 d1 44 00 00 20 79  d1 44 09 00 00 00 00 00  |.D.D.. y.D......|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

(Bytes with `size` are 0x9c - 0x9f)

Could you please explain me why this size is zero? Or may be, somebody could point me to a doc, describing `vfat` directory entries with more details?

(I'm on Ubuntu 3.11.10.3, running as a guest OS in VMWare Fusion on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

A directory is not actually a file, but a logical way for a system to organize itself. The way the directories would be stored (depending on the file system) in some sort of table. For example: **FAT** uses a **F** ile **A** llocation **T** able.

So the size of the directory would be dependent upon the amount of space it takes up in that table, more directories equal larger table(s). It may be just a couple bytes.

I could be wrong on some points, but I am pretty sure this is why you are not seeing the size in the hex (as it is mostly a pointer).